# elastic search shutting down throws TransportNodesShutdownAction$1$2 not found

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elastic search 1.1.0.

While trying to shutdown the elastic search I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError. Code used to shutdown and stack trace is given below.

Maven:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Code: `node.client().admin().cluster().prepareNodesShutdown().execute().get();`

```
2015-08-05 21:45:11,113 [Thread-15] INFO  org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.node.shutdown internalInfo  - [Captain Ultra] [cluster_shutdown]: done shutting down all nodes except master, proceeding to master

INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.node.shutdown.TransportNodesShutdownAction$1$2.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.node.shutdown.TransportNodesShutdownAction$1.run(TransportNodesShutdownAction.java:153)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/admin/cluster/node/shutdown/TransportNodesShutdownAction$1$2
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.node.shutdown.TransportNodesShutdownAction$1.run(TransportNodesShutdownAction.java:153)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.node.shutdown.TransportNodesShutdownAction$1$2
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        ... 2 more
```

This issue is not allowing elastic search to shutdown gracefully. Tomcat is waiting for certain period(timeout) and then killing all those threads forcefully. 
How to fix this issue?

Same issue is coming with 1.0.0 also.

Comment: Can you check the libraries that you provided to Tomcat and see if, indeed, you have 1.1.0 in there? Also, I'm assuming the cluster is using 1.1.0, as well, right?

Comment: Yes. Tomcat is having 1.1.0. How to know which version of cluster is being used. Because i just created the cluster using code shown below.   node = nodeBuilder().settings(settings).clusterName(clusterName).node();
  node.start();

Comment: Oh, so you are embedding Elasticsearch in your webapp?

Comment: yes. Elastic search is embedded with webapp

Comment: The elasticsearch jar is under WEB-INF/lib or under TOMCAT/lib?

Comment: That jar is present in WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: Can you check under both WEB-INF/lib and TOMCAT/lib if you have any other elasticsearch jar? The idea is to have a single elasticsearch jar in the classpath.

Comment: No. elasticsearch.jar is only in WEB-INF/lib. And i tried to extract elasticsearch.jar and I'm able to see TransportNodesShutdownAction$1$2.class. If that class is present, why it is giving ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Probably because you have somewhere a second elasticsearch jar. Or a .jar that contains elasticsearch classes in it. And Tomcat loads that class multiple times because it exists in multiple jars.

Comment: I verified in POM.xml dependencies hierarchy. elasticsearch.jar is not included as part of any other jar.

Comment: Look at [this link](http://muzso.hu/2009/03/17/debugging-tomcat-class-loading-issues) and try to look at what Tomcat is loading.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution. Elastic search is trying to shutdown in separate thread. By the time elastic search tries to access TransportNodesShutdownAction, tomcat will unload elastic jar from its class loader. So adding some sleep statement or adding elastic and its dependent jar to tomcat/lib will solve the problem.